# Rotating an image with java GUI

Tags: java

I have tried rotating my image in java GUI. This code seems to work for everyone but me. What am I doing wrong and what should I change so that the image is rotated?

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
AffineTransform a = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(3.14159/4,xloc,yloc);
a.setToTranslation(xloc,yloc);
g2d.drawImage(horse,a,null);
```

The translation works, but not the image rotation. What should I do?

Comment: *"What should I do?"* - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Having had a glance over the code, you are translating the graphics context by `xloc,yloc` but also rotating the graphics context at the anchor point `xloc,yloc` - transformations are compounding. Perhaps, instead, translate the context to `xloc,yloc` first, then rotate it at `0x0` instead

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what `setToTranslation` does. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#setToTranslation(double,%20double)):

> `public void setToTranslation(double tx, double ty)`
>
> Sets this transform to a translation transformation. The matrix representing this transform becomes:
>
> ```
> [   1    0    tx  ]
> [   0    1    ty  ]
> [   0    0    1   ]
> ```

So your rotation matrix is overwritten with a translation matrix. Consider using [`translate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#translate(double,%20double)) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. I really appreciate the help.